# Getting an Android Database Setup?

Tags: android, database, installation

Typically, for a WinForm or a Web App, I create the database and tables through the RDBMS or through a separate install process. However, I haven't seen anything of the sort in Android. All the examples I've seen have the database creation scripts embedded in an activity like [this](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/09/create-android-database.html).

The best thing I can come up with now is to call a method from the data access constructor to check whether the database is installed - if not - install it. However, this seems like a lot of overhead to me.

What's the cleanest way to execute a android database install and then forget about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SQLLiteOpenHelper (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), the onCreate method will be called only if the database doesn't exist. onUpgrade will be called when a new version of the database is introduced.
IF the database already exists, and no version upgrade occured, these methods won't be executed.

There is no need for implementing if-else checks in your activity.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);
    }
}
```